# Finger print on ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, activex, fingerprint, biometrics

is there a way to use finger print scanner on ASP.NET project? If yes, can someone provide me a sample codes or project solutions. this device will be used in log in system for a website. also, I would really appreciate if you can breakdown the steps clearly on what to first and what's next. Thanks alot

Comment: Welcometo [so], questions usually require some code to demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. This is also a bit of a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Plus we would need more information to assist, are you expecting everyone to have a scanner or is this an intranet site? See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713573/asp-net-webservice-prompt-for-finger-print-reader?rq=1

Comment: Also what's the point when this is done out of the box with hardware: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c00958213

Comment: I haven't started yet with the codes, etc. because I don't where to start that's why I'm asking. Yes on every PC will have a scanner to use for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Your question shows a misunderstanding of both fingerprint scanners and web sites.

Finger print scanners mainly store the password username and password, and then in response to a finger press enter that information into the appropriate spots.

In general web pages do not have access to the clients hardware, if they do (activex, java-applet, silverlight) it's generally limited and still probably best to just have a client side application.

Comment: Yes, I heard about using active-x for this. can you share me the general steps to be able to make it work using active-x? just general steps will do. I'm new to this project and haven't use active-x nor this scanner. and you mentioned "its generally limited", how limited? I just need to authenticate user using the scanner, that if the authentication failed they will not be logged in. Thanks!

Comment: Active X is IE only.  But if you go that route mainly it's like writing any other control.  It's generally limited, in that the various ways of doing things inside the browser are limited for security reasons.  Most finger print scanners do this kind of thing out of the box.  I'd take a look at what you've got before even thinking about writing code.